# How to compile Fortran with `real sepaa[allocatable](:)` syntax?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile this program / module? (modulos.f) in Fortran

```
      module vars_common
          real sepaa[allocatable](:)
          real sepan[allocatable](:)
          real rt[allocatable](:) 
          real xob[allocatable](:)
          real npx[allocatable](:)
          real*8 bb[allocatable](:)
          real*8 bl[allocatable](:)
          real*8 bu[allocatable](:)
          real*8 cvec[allocatable](:)
          real*8 ww[allocatable](:)
          real*8 a[allocatable](:,:)
          real*8 xi[allocatable](:)
          real*8 q[allocatable](:,:)
          real*8 dd[allocatable](:,:)
          !variables escalares
          integer maxm_var, maxn_var, nrowa_var
          integer liwork_var,lwork_var, maxbnd_var
      end module vars_common
      
*********************************************************************     
       subroutine allocate_data
          !maxm, maxn,maxbnd,mp
          use vars_common
          parameter(mg=1000, mp=2000)
          integer ind
          allocate(sepaa(0:maxm_var),sepan(0:maxm_var),rt(0:maxm_var),
     *    stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria'  
          allocate(xob(maxm_var),npx(0:mp), 
     *    stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria' 
          allocate(bb(0:maxm_var),bl(maxbnd_var),bu(maxbnd_var),
     *    stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria' 
          allocate(cvec(maxn_var), ww(maxn_var), 
     *    stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria' 
          allocate(a(0:maxm_var,0:maxn_var), stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria'
          allocate(xi(maxn_var),q(maxn_var,maxn_var),
     *    stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria'
          allocate(dd(maxn_var,maxn_var),stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'sin memoria'
      end subroutine allocate_data
          
**********************************************************************
      subroutine deallocate_data
          use vars_common
          integer ind
          deallocate(sepaa,sepan,rt, stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'problema liberando espacio' 
          deallocate(xob,npx,stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'problema liberando espacio'
          deallocate(bb,bl,bu,stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'problema liberando espacio'
          deallocate(cvec,a,stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'problema liberando espacio'
          deallocate(xi,q,stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'problema liberando espacio'
          deallocate(dd,stat=ind)
          if (ind.ne.0) stop 'problema liberando espacio'
      end subroutine deallocate_data
***********************************************************************
```

I don't know what version of Fortran is, but I tried with the following commands in a terminal in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

**gfortran modulos.f** I got this error message:
> modulos.f:2:21:

```
    2 |           real sepaa[allocatable](:)
      |                     1
Fatal Error: Coarrays disabled at (1), use ‘-fcoarray=’ to enable
compilation terminated.
```

**gfortran -fcoarray=lib -c modulos.f** or **gfortran -fcoarray=single -c modulos.f**
I got this error message:

```
modulos.f:2:33:

    2 |           real sepaa[allocatable](:)
      |                                 1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:3:33:

    3 |           real sepan[allocatable](:)
      |                                 1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:4:30:

    4 |           real rt[allocatable](:)
      |                              1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:5:31:

    5 |           real xob[allocatable](:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:6:31:

    6 |           real npx[allocatable](:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:7:32:

    7 |           real*8 bb[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:8:32:

    8 |           real*8 bl[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:9:32:

    9 |           real*8 bu[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:10:34:

   10 |           real*8 cvec[allocatable](:)
      |                                  1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:11:32:

   11 |           real*8 ww[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:12:31:

   12 |           real*8 a[allocatable](:,:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:13:32:

   13 |           real*8 xi[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:14:31:

   14 |           real*8 q[allocatable](:,:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:15:32:

   15 |           real*8 dd[allocatable](:,:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:24:13:

   24 |           use vars_common
      |             1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘vars_common.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

**gfortran -fcoarray=none -c modulos.f** I got this error message:

```
gfortran -fcoarray=none -c modulos.f 
modulos.f:2:21:

    2 |           real sepaa[allocatable](:)
      |                     1
Fatal Error: Coarrays disabled at (1), use ‘-fcoarray=’ to enable
compilation terminated.
```

**gfortran -fcoarray=single -c modulos.f** I got this error message:

```
gfortran -fcoarray=single -c modulos.f
modulos.f:2:33:

    2 |           real sepaa[allocatable](:)
      |                                 1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:3:33:

    3 |           real sepan[allocatable](:)
      |                                 1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:4:30:

    4 |           real rt[allocatable](:)
      |                              1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:5:31:

    5 |           real xob[allocatable](:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:6:31:

    6 |           real npx[allocatable](:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:7:32:

    7 |           real*8 bb[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:8:32:

    8 |           real*8 bl[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:9:32:

    9 |           real*8 bu[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:10:34:

   10 |           real*8 cvec[allocatable](:)
      |                                  1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:11:32:

   11 |           real*8 ww[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:12:31:

   12 |           real*8 a[allocatable](:,:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:13:32:

   13 |           real*8 xi[allocatable](:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:14:31:

   14 |           real*8 q[allocatable](:,:)
      |                               1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:15:32:

   15 |           real*8 dd[allocatable](:,:)
      |                                1
Error: Upper bound of last coarray dimension must be ‘*’ at (1)
modulos.f:24:13:

   24 |           use vars_common
      |             1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘vars_common.mod’ for reading 

at (1): No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

Could you help me to find a solution, please? Preferably using gfortran as the compiler. Thank you

Comment: Please do not put relevant code to some Google drive link. Copy and paste the relevant code here. See [mcve] and [ask]. The `[allocatable]` does not look like standard Fortran. Is the code supposed to use coarrays? What are the "similar errors" exactly? I suppose they are quite different after all. Is it your code or someone else's code? Is it known to compile for someone?

Comment: I am sorry. I edited my question, and I pasted the code there. Also, I included other error messages. This is part of a bigger program developed by my Ph.D. supervisor in 2003. It was not well documented/commented on, so my task is to understand as much as possible, and then I have to build new things using this as a reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `[allocatable]` is not standard Fortran.

Instead of

```
      real sepaa[allocatable](:)
      real sepan[allocatable](:)
```

Fortran requires

```
      real, allocatable :: sepaa(:)
      real, allocatable :: sepan(:)
```

and so on. Alternatives with the `dimension` attribute or with a separate `allocatable` statement also exist.

If it is not at too many places, I suggest to make this correction manually.

You can try try asking your supervisor what kind of syntax it is and how it is supposed to be compiled. It can happen that they no longer know where they learned it but at least they might know which compiler they used to use for this. But I suggest correcting the code instead if searching for and buying some compiler that will accept it as an extension.

---

What gfortran has been telling you is that standard Fortran uses the square brackets for [coarrays](https://coarrays.sourceforge.io/doc.html). Those are used for parallel processing

```
real, allocatable :: A(:)[:]
```

I do not think this is related to your code.

Comment: Thank you, @Vladimir F. I will follow your suggestions. I will come back with the result.

Comment: I was able to compile the program following your suggestions @Vladimir F Thank you!